# Add factors to a df by subsetting rows containing certain letters

Tags: r

This is my data:

```
  Year variable value
 1951     MF12 1.441
 1952     MF12 2.068
 1953     RF12 2.008  
 1954     RF12 2.044
 1955     MW12 2.288
 1956     RW12 1.800
```

Where MF= Managed Frame, RF= Reserve Frame, MW= Managed Wind, RW= Reserve Wind. So in total 4 different levels = Managed, Reserve, Frame, Wind.

I want to create two types of factors based on these levels and add them as columns to the data frame. Factor 1 will be management.type (Managed, Reserve) and Factor 2 will be object.type (Frame, Wind).

Something like this:

```
Year variable value Management Object
1951   MF12 1.37845 Managed      Frame 
1952   MF12 1.38950 Managed      Frame
1953   MW12 1.55510 Managed      Wind
1954   RF12 1.66125 Reserve      Frame
1955   RW12 1.62600 Reserve      Wind
1956   RW13 1.58760 Reserve      Wind
```

How can I do this using R (rather than going back and sorting in excel)? I think in terms of Management type maybe use the `start.with` command to sort by starting with 'M' or 'R', but not sure how to do that. In terms of Object, is there a way to sort by words that contain letter 'F' or 'W'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

- `case_when()` from `dplyr` that has the benefit over `ifelse()` that dealing with more than two cases is very manageable.
- `substr()` to extract the first letter and then the second letter, for more complicated checks `grepl()` with some regex might be necessary.

```
df$Management <- dplyr::case_when(
  substr(df$variable, 1, 1) == "M" ~ "Managed",
  substr(df$variable, 1, 1) == "R" ~ "Reserved",
)

df$Object <- dplyr::case_when(
  substr(df$variable, 2, 2) == "F" ~ "Frame",
  substr(df$variable, 2, 2) == "W" ~ "Wind",
)

df
  Year variable value Management Object
1 1951     MF12 1.441    Managed  Frame
2 1952     MF12 2.068    Managed  Frame
3 1953     RF12 2.008   Reserved  Frame
4 1954     RF12 2.044   Reserved  Frame
5 1955     MW12 2.288    Managed   Wind
6 1956     RW12 1.800   Reserved   Wind
```

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Year = 1951:1956, 
  variable = c("MF12", "MF12", "RF12", "RF12", "MW12", "RW12"), 
  value = c(1.441, 2.068, 2.008, 2.044, 2.288, 1.8),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `grepl()` and `ifelse()` a try:

```
df$Management <- ifelse(test = grepl(pattern = "M", x = df$variable), 
                        yes  = "Managed", 
                        no   = "Reserve")
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. May I ask so that I know for the future, what is the role of 'test' in this function?

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>%
    mutate(Management = factor(str_extract(variable, "^."),
          levels = c("M", "R"), labels = c("Managed", "Reserved")), 
          Object = factor(str_extract(variable, "(?<=^.)."), 
          levels = c("F", "W"), labels = c("Frame", "Wind")))
#   Year variable value Management Object
#1 1951     MF12 1.441    Managed  Frame
#2 1952     MF12 2.068    Managed  Frame
#3 1953     RF12 2.008   Reserved  Frame
#4 1954     RF12 2.044   Reserved  Frame
#5 1955     MW12 2.288    Managed   Wind
#6 1956     RW12 1.800   Reserved   Wind
```